# how to grant a user permission to create databases?

Tags: mysql

I use **phpMyAdmin** powered by Mamp (free version) to manage **Mysql** databases.

I need to know how to grant a user permission to create databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

For further information, please see [**MySQL Documentation on GRANT syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

Comment: should I run this in the terminal ?